# Splitting field over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am reviewing for my exam, i need your help to answer the following problem:

Let $f(x)=x^6+3\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$

Let $\alpha$ be a root of $f(x)$ and $L=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$.

> Show that $L$ is a splitting field for $f(x)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Hint: Show that $w=\frac{1+\alpha^3}{2}$ is a primitive sixth root of unity.

Thanks

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: i don't know how to use the hint to answer, i will be gretful is you help me.

Comment: A number $\beta$ is a sixth root of $1$ if and only if $\beta^6-1=0$. However, it is a *primitive* root if and only if it is the zero of one specific factor of $x^6-1$, wich is munch munch... Once you have the hint, you're practically done.

Comment: I know that A number $r$ is an $n$th root of unity if $r^n=1$ and a primitive $n$th root of unity if, in addition, $n$ is the smallest integer of $k=1, ..., n $for which $r^k=1$. but how to use that?

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:* The roots of $x^6+3$ are $\alpha\omega^k$ for $k=0,\dots,5$, where $\omega$ is a primitive sixth root of unity.

Now, 
$2\omega = 1+\alpha^3 \implies 8\omega^3 = (1+\alpha^3)^3 = -8$ and so $\omega^3 = -1$. Since $\omega\ne1$, $\omega$ is a primitive sixth root of unity in $L$.

Therefore, all roots of $x^6+3$ are in $L$.

Comment: we need to show that these roots are in $L$, i tried to do that but i can not answer.

Comment: @siiwar Obviously $\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. Now if only we could use the hint from the book to derive that $\omega \in \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$

Comment: But how to Show that $w=\frac{1+\alpha^3}{2}$ is a primitive sixth root of unity?I know  $w$ is an $6$th root of unity if $w^6=1$ and a primitive $6$th root of unity if, in addition, $6$ is the smallest integer of $k=1, ..., 6 $for which $w^k=1$. but how to prove  that?