# Galois group of $x^6+3$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I need your help to answer the following problem:

Let $f(x)=x^6+3\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$

Let $\alpha$ be a root of $f(x)$ and $L=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$.

> a) Show that $L$ is a splitting field for $f(x)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Hint: Show that $w=\frac{1+\alpha^3}{2}$ is a primitive sixth root of unity.

> b) determine $Gal(L/\mathbb{Q})$ .

I answered question a) but i don't manage to answer question b).

Thanks

Comment: Start by proving $f$ is irreducible over the rationals.

Comment: i proved that $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ by using Einstein's cretiria with p=3 but how to use that to answer?

Comment: Saying "I answered question a)" is a bit disingenuous, considering https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2525878/splitting-field-over-mathbbq where you asked it and it was answered for you.

Comment: Proving irreducibility (together with the rest of what you know) tells you the order of the Galois group.

Comment: how that please?

Comment: Well, what theorem do you know about the number of elements of the Galois group?

Comment: do you mean Fundamental theorem of Galois theory?

Comment: I'm not interested in what you call it. I mean, do you know a theorem that relates the order of the Galois group to the degree of the normal extension?